# Is there a way to show the full path of a Samba share on a Finder window title?

Tags: finder, smb

I mostly have the same folder name on different shares. These can get confusing after a while. So, is there a way to show the shared folder name and not the mount name on a Finder window title?

EDIT: I'm explaining on the below screenshot.

[image: my issue]

Comment: That's not the path.  The path would be `/Volumes/drupal7`.  What you are asking for is the *mount point* and that can't be shown on Finder (AFAIK).  Go to Terminal, type the command `mount` and you will see both the path and the mount point.

Comment: Mount point is `/Volume/drupal7`, according to https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/91961/86423

Comment: Sorry.. need coffee.  That your `mount` (no point).  Your *mount point* is synonymous with your path.  Still, (notwithstanding my error in terminology) what you're looking for is not provided by Finder.

Comment: Is this something that can be done with some Automator help?

Comment: You could get the path with the help of Automater/AppleScript, but the question is...where/how would you display it?  I don't know enough AppleScript to answer that accurately and I don't think you can "modify" a Finder window.

Answer (score 1):

An easier way in the GUI is to right/ctl click the top (dark grey) area of the finder window, select "Customise Toolbar" and drag in the "Path" icon.

Clicking this with the desired folder highlighted will give the path.

You could then drag the folder / share into the list on the left to save as a bookmark and right/ctl click it to rename to something more meaningful to you. Thus not having to worry about the path in the future.

Another quick way to find the path is to drag the folder into a terminal window which will populate it with the mounted path.